# Reset token in vue resource - Vue2

Tags: vuejs2, vue-resource

In the main.js file i have set the vue resource to use auth headers with every requests:

```
Vue.use( VueResource )

let auth = validToken()
if( auth ) {
  Vue.http.interceptors.push( ( request, next ) => {
    request.headers.set( 'Authorization', auth.token )
    request.headers.set( 'Accept', 'application/json' )
    next()
  } )
}
```

And in the logout, i am trying to delete the header this way,

```
resetVueRsr: () => {
  this.$http.headers.common['Authorization'] = null
}
```

And when a user log in, then resetting the new token to the global Vue resource like this,

```
this.$http.headers.common['Authorization'] = res.body.token
```

But once a new user is logging in the site, the vue resource still sending previous token with each request. What i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I checked [the source](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/6072148a56ac35fd1f599d80000f02cf15df47fe/src/http/index.js#L26), and it looks like all defined interceptors are added in some [internal array](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/fe268fa1d6053ede5f34aef9a11e1a424a70446c/src/http/client/index.js#L54), and then used for requests.

According to your code sample, you obtain an object with initial token somehow and then pass it inside your arrow function, so JS creates a closure for this to make this object available inside the function, and I think a lifetime of this closure is equal to a lifetime of your app. I assume that you have a sort of SPA.

Also from the source it looks like interceptors are not related to common headers, so your way of deleting and resetting won't change your interceptor.